# C# ExecuteScalar() returns null but the data is inserted in the SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.

Every time the data is successfully inserted into the database but always it returns a null value. In the SQL Server I only created the table with only auto-increment on the first column('Id'). My table looks like this:

| Column_Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int |
| DateTime | datetime |
| ClientName | nvarchar |
| ClientNumber | nvarchar |
| TotalPrice | float |

My code looks like this:

```
try
{ 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = _conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO appointmentTable(DateTime,ClientName,ClientNumber,TotalPrice) VALUES( @datee, @clientName ,@clientNumber, @totalPrice);";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datee", newAppointment.GetDateTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", newAppointment.GetClientName());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientNumber", newAppointment.GetClientNumber());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalPrice", newAppointment.GetTotalPrice());
    _conn.Open();
    int idAdded = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    newAppointment.SetId(idAdded);
    AppointmentServiceRepository.getInstance().AddServicesToAppointment(newAppointment);
    _conn.Close();
    return true;
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As an aside its highly recommended to [**not** use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). And certainly don't convert your date to a string to insert it, insert it as a native datetime.

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) you'll see you need to select the new id for it to be returned.

Comment: Without the coversion I was getting this error about parsing the dateTime to string.

Comment: Thats probably because you are using AddWithValue - use the regular add method and set the datatype correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by selecting the new Id? In the documentation says that ExecuteScalar executes the query and returns the value on the first column and the first row of the result set.

Comment: There is an exact example in the documents linked to above showing how to do what you are trying to do - please read it.

Comment: I understand now, thank you.

Comment: Separate note, `TotalPrice` is is a poor data type choice for a price. By using a `float` you are saying you are happy with rounding errors, which when dealing with money is a very very bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the SQL function SCOPE_IDENTITY(), as follows

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO 
appointmentTable(DateTime,ClientName,ClientNumber,TotalPrice) VALUES( @datee, @clientName 
,@clientNumber, @totalPrice); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try OUTPUT clause to return the newly inserted id.[Read more on OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO 
appointmentTable(DateTime,ClientName,ClientNumber,TotalPrice) 
OUTPUT inserted.ID 
VALUES( @datee, @clientName,@clientNumber, @totalPrice); "
```